# I am getting this error for the below code please help me

Tags: error

ERROR:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Decimal) from the type Map<String,List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>>

```
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {
    public static void updateWorkOrders(List<Case> caseList) {
        List<case> newCases = new List<Case>();
        Map<String,Integer> result=getDueDate(caseList);
        list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> itemsListToinsert= new list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>();
        Map<String,list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>> resultItmes=getMaintainanceItems(caseList);
        for(Case c : caseList){
            if(c.status=='closed')
                if(c.type=='Repair' || c.type=='Routine Maintenance'){
                    Case newCase = new Case();
                    newCase.Status='New';
                    newCase.Origin='web';
                    newCase.Type='Routine Maintenance';
                    newCase.Subject='Routine Maintenance of Vehicle';
                    newCase.Vehicle__c=c.Vehicle__c;
                    newCase.Equipment__c=c.Equipment__c;
                    newCase.Date_Reported__c=Date.today();
                    newcase.Case_Id__c=c.Case_Id__c;
                    if(result.get(c.Id)!=null)
                        newCase.Date_Due__c=Date.today()+result.get(c.Id);
                    else
                            newCase.Date_Due__c=Date.today();
                    newCases.add(newCase);
                }
        }
        if(newCases.size()>0)
        {
            insert newCases;

            for(Case c : newCases){
                List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> temp =  resultItmes.get(c.Case_Id__c);
                if(temp !=null){
                    for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c row:temp){
                        Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newitem = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
                        newitem.Equipment__c=row.Equipment__c;
                        newitem.Maintenance_Request__c= c.Id;
                        newitem.Quantity__c= row.Quantity__c;
                        itemsListToinsert.add(newitem);

                    }
                }

            }


        }

        if(itemsListToinsert.size()>0)
            insert itemsListToinsert;
    }
    //
    public static  Map<String,Integer> getDueDate(List<case> CaseIDs){
        Map<String,Integer> result = new Map<String,Integer>();
        Map<Id, case> caseKeys = new Map<Id, case> (CaseIDs);
        List<AggregateResult> wpc=[select Maintenance_Request__r.ID cID,min(Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c)cycle
        from Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c where  Maintenance_Request__r.ID in :caseKeys.keySet() and Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c != null group by             Maintenance_Request__r.ID ];
        for(AggregateResult res :wpc){
            Integer addDays=0;
            if(res.get('cycle')!=null)
                addDays+=Integer.valueOf(res.get('cycle'));
            result.put((String)res.get('cID'),addDays);
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static Map<String,list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>> getMaintainanceItems(List<case> CaseIDs){

        Map<String,list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>> mapofMaintainanceItems = new Map<String,list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>>();
        Map<Id, case> caseKeys = new Map<Id, case> (CaseIDs);
        list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> lstrec = new  list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>([select id ,Maintenance_Request__c,Equipment__c,Quantity__c
        from Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c where  Maintenance_Request__r.ID in :caseKeys.keySet() ]);

        for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c row:lstrec){

            if (mapofMaintainanceItems.containsKey(row.Maintenance_Request__c)) {
                List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> temp = mapofMaintainanceItems.get(row.Maintenance_Request__c);
                temp.add(row);
                mapofMaintainanceItems.put(row.Maintenance_Request__c, temp);
            }
            else{
                mapofMaintainanceItems.put(row.Maintenance_Request__c, new List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> { row });
            }

        }

        return mapofMaintainanceItems;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
mapofMaintainanceItems.get(row.Maintenance_Request__c);
```

Your `Maintenance_Request__c` would be a decimal, you can either convert that to String or you can change you map to `Map<Decimal,list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>>`